# Windows 10, lost hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

I have a Samsung series 5 ultrabook and this particular model has a 23GB SSD and 500GB HDD.

I installed the Windows 7 on the HDD and used the SSD for some scripts and small games.

I recently upgraded to Win 10 and basically just lost the SSD drive. I tried checking on a partition manager and this is what I see:

[image]

Unfortunately, I have no idea what these mean and the stuff on google just went over my head.

Anyone wanna shed some light here?

EDIT:

Just want to clear something up, when I said "lost the SSD drive", I meant it was on drive `G:` and now I can't access drive `G:` anymore.

Comment: Was it used as a data drive, or to speed up the booting time?

Comment: When I bought it it was used to speed up booting time. But I've formatted the drive since and used it for the aforementioned games.

Comment: Your SSD seems to be there just fine; it's called "Disk 2". It looks like what you need to do is simply to assign a drive letter to the partition. I don't know exactly how that's done in Windows 10, but right click on the "22.36 GB" entry and look for something like "Change drive letter", "Change mapping" or similar. Then set it to `G:` and you should be good to go. (If anyone wants to take this plus some familiarity with Windows 10 and turn it into an answer instead, feel free to.)

Comment: Yeah, I can see that it's still there, but it's just not accessible. It also looks like it's been used up whereas I only used about half of the space before. I think Win 10 used it as a bootup disk or something. BTW, I don't get any of those options (or anything similar) when I right-click it.

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to access the SSD before and look inside it is not just sufficient to assign a drive letter as recommended in the comments.

There is either information there that you want to recover or not.
In the first case you could use the free and open source software Testdisk to recover lost partition information.

If you do not care about the content you could simply partition and format the SSD.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, it is lost partition, EaseUS partition manager can't help you, what you should do is try to recover Partition, Use [EaseUS Partition Recovery](http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/) to find the lost partition back, or lost data.